# Why does POSIX require certain shell built-ins to have an external implementation?

Tags: shell, posix, shell-builtin

From [this question about whether printf is a built-in for yash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/496259/173210), comes [this answer that quotes the POSIX standard](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/496289/173210).

The answer points out that the POSIX search sequence is to find an external implementation of the desired command, and then, if the shell has implemented it as a built-in, run the built-in. (For built-ins that aren't *special built-ins*.)

Why does POSIX have this requirement for an external implementation to exist before allowing an internal implementation to be run?

It seems...  arbitrary, so I am curious.

Comment: I believe that is a way to enable/disable builtins if desired/required.

Comment: Disabling the built-in by removing the external implementation? Now there are no commands of name `printf` available.

Comment: @studog, so create an empty file with the same name as the built-in, turn on the execute bit, and put it in a directory in your PATH.  :P

Comment: @Wildcard A strictly compliant shell would then see the name while searching the `PATH` and then call the built-in utility, not the external script. What if you'd want to call the external script in your path? Hmm... This seems to call for a table describing the different possibilities. There is one [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/xrat/V4_xcu_chap02.html#tag_23_02_09_02), but it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @Kusalananda, re your first sentence, that was my point.  Hence why I said to create an *empty* file.

Comment: @Kusalananda Sadly I can not recommend to use `builtin` as the spec explicitly disables it (and yash can use it while in posix). But you have, at least, three options to call external utilities: (1) The widely known full path: `/usr/bin/printf` (2) Have and use an external which that correctly finds external utilities and execute `$(which printf)` and (3) the much recomended tool to call programs in the PATH: `env printf`.

Comment: @Kusalananda In the table, the first two make sense to me (and work) `ls` calls the shell own function (or built-in), `command ls` should call the external `ls` (but doesn't work in yash bug?). The following two are externally used commands, in a makefile and in Perl (maybe?). The last one looks incorrect to me. The PATH to search for a command name (in the parent shell) can not change by an assignment.

Comment: @studog That was the intent, that doesn't work in practice. Only a command like `enable` could do that reliably.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## This is an "as if" rule.

Simply put: The behaviour of the shell as users see it should not change if an implementation decides to make a standard external command also available as shell built-in.

The contrast that I showed at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/496291/5132 between the behaviours of (on the one hand) the PD Korn, MirBSD Korn, and Heirloom Bourne shells; (on the other hand) the Z, 93 Korn, Bourne Again, and Debian Almquist shells; and (on the gripping hand) the Watanabe shell highlights this.

For the shells that do not have `printf` as a built-in, removing `/usr/bin` from `PATH` makes an invocation of `printf` stop working.  The POSIX conformant behaviour, exhibited by the Watanabe shell in its conformant mode, causes the same result.  The behaviour of the shell that has a `printf` built-in is *as if* it were invoking an external command.

Whereas the behaviour of all of the non-conformant shells does not alter if `/usr/bin` is removed from `PATH`, and they do *not* behave as if they were invoking an external command.

What the standard is trying to guarantee to you is that shells can build-in all sorts of normally external commands (or implement them as its own shell functions), and you'll still get the same behaviour from the built-ins as you did with the external commands if you adjust `PATH` to stop the commands from being found.  `PATH` remains your tool for selecting and controlling what commands you can invoke.

(As explained at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/448799/5132, years ago people chose the personality of their Unix by changing what was on `PATH`.)

One might opine that making the command *always work* irrespective of whether it can be found on `PATH` *is in fact the point* of making normally external commands built-in.  (It's why my nosh toolset just gained a built-in `printenv` command in version 1.38, in fact.  Although this is *not* a shell.)

But the standard is giving you the guarantee that you'll see the *same* behaviour for regular external commands that are not on `PATH` from the shell as you will see from other non-shell programs invoking the `execvpe()` function, and the shell will not magically be able to run (apparently) ordinary external commands that other programs cannot find with the same `PATH`.  Everything works self-consistently from the user's perspective, and `PATH` is the tool for controlling how it works.

## Further reading

- [Why are POSIX mandatory utilities not built into the shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/347188/)
- [Why is echo a shell built in command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1355/)
- [How does bash execute commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/421306/)

Answer (score 15):

That's quite absurd and that's why no shell is implementing it in its default mode.

The standard's [rationale](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xcu_chap02.html#tag_23_02_09_02) and its illustrating [example](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xcu_chap02.html#tag_23_02_09_02) suggest that this was a botched attempt to have a *regular* built-in associated with a path, and let the user override it by having their own binary appear before it in `PATH` (eg. a `printf` built-in associated with `/usr/bin/printf` could be overridden by the `/foo/bin/printf` external command by setting `PATH=/foo/bin:$PATH`).

However, the standard did not end up requiring that, but something completely [different](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01_01) (and also useless and unexpected).

You can read more about it in this [bug report](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=854#c2495). Quoting from from the [final accepted text](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=854#c2495):

> Many existing implementations execute a regular built-in without
>   performing a PATH search. This behavior does not match the normative
>   text, and it does not allow script authors to override regular
>   built-in utilities via a specially crafted PATH. In addition, the
>   rationale explains that the **intention is to allow authors to override**
>   built-ins by modifying PATH, but **this is not what the normative text
>   says**.

FWIW, I don't think there's any shell implementing the revised requirements from the accepted text, either.

Comment: See also the discussion at http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.standards.posix.austin.general/12525 (and there have been several others).

Comment: Also https://github.com/att/ast/issues/370 (long)

Answer (score 3):

Follow-up vis-a-vis `echo` vs `printf`:

*(Below,* `builtin` *means "special builtin", and "regular builtin"s are not considered to be builtins by me since they are not built into the shell)*

The first POSIX standardization committee could not agree on how to
standardize echo, so they compromised by issuing that if it was passed flags (`-e,-n,-E`, etc.) or if any arguments contained escape sequences (`\n,\c,\t`, etc.) that the behavior was to be defined by the implementing shell rather than POSIX. Instead, the `printf` command was added and given well-defined behavior.
(source: Classic Shell Scripting, by Robbins and Beebe).

Although `printf` is well-defined, some shells do not have `printf` as a
builtin command (e.g. `mksh`). Instead, they use `printf` from `/usr/bin/`.
This meant all scripts run from that shell would print the same on a
given operating system (Ubuntu, Fedora, etc.), but that they wouldn't
necessarily print the same across OSs (in fact, many users changed the
`printf` in their `/usr/bin` for this reason).

Alternatively, shells with `printf` as a builtin would print the same
regardless of OS, but only if used as implemented for the shell. However,
since `printf` behavior is defined by the POSIX standard, that isn't necessarily
a concern for programmers. However, if `PATH` were overriden for shells that use `printf` from `/usr/bin/`, `printf` wouldn't be found.

Though all shells have `echo` as a builtin, some interpret escape sequences
directly (e.g. `ash`) while others (most) require a `-e` flag: the behavior is
not defined by POSIX, but by the shell.

One of the main annoyances of `echo` vs. `printf` is that `echo` prints new
lines at the end of the string by default, but `printf` does not. `printf`
requires the `\n` escape sequence to print new lines. Conversely, to prevent
`echo` from printing a new line, the `\c` escape sequence is required
(potentially, also requiring the `-e` flag).

`printf` is recommended for maximum portability since its behavior is defined by POSIX, but I personally find explicitly printing a new line at the end of each line is quite annoying (most lines I write require a new line at the end and I very rarely need to suppress `echo`'s printing of new lines). On the other hand,
`echo` is always available since it's a builtin (no risk of not being found on $PATH) and a simple check can be performed to determine whether the `-e` flag is needed and a corresponding aliased `echo` made:

```bsh
#! /bin/sh -

# Determine if "builtin" command exists.
BUILTIN='builtin'
  
if ! ("${BUILTIN}" echo 123 >/dev/null 2>&1); then
  BUILTIN=''
fi
export BUILTIN

ECHO='echo -e'

if ${BUILTIN} [ "`echo -e test`" = '-e test' ]; then
  ECHO='echo'
fi
export ECHO

# Now use "${ECHO}" where you would normally use "echo"...
```

Personally, I prefer to do this and only use `printf` if I need special formatting.

**UPDATE:**
I should give proper credit where credit is due. The shell code above was taken directly from `shunit2`. Credit goes to Kate Ward and the `shunit2` development team for that one! (Well done ;) )

Answer (score 1):

Adding this as well ([*Classic Shell Scripting* by Robbins and Beebe](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596005954) is a **great** book):

> The shell has a number of commands that are built-in. This means that the shell itself executes the command, instead of running an external
> program in a separate process. Furthermore, POSIX distinguishes
> between “special” built-ins and “regular” built-ins. [Most regular
> built-ins] have to be built-in for the shell to function correctly
> (e.g., `read`). Others are typically built into the shell only for
> efficiency (e.g., `true` and `false`). The standard allows other
> commands to be built-in for efficiency as well, ***but all regular
> built-ins must be accessible as separate programs that can be executed
> directly by other binary programs.*** The distinction between special
> and regular built-in  commands comes into play when the shell searches
> for commands to execute. The command-search order is special built-ins
> first, then shell functions, then regular built-ins, and finally
> external commands found by searching the directories listed in
> `$PATH`. This search order makes it possible to define shell functions
> that extend or override regular shell builtins. This feature is used
> most often in interactive shells. For example, suppose you would like
> the shell's prompt to contain the last component of the current
> directory's pathname. The easiest way to make this happen is to have
> the shell change `PS1` each time you change directories. You could
> just write your own [`cd`] function [for this]. **There is one small
> fly in the ointment here. How does the shell function access the
> functionality of the "real" `cd` command?...What's needed is an
> "escape hatch" that tells the shell to bypas the search for functions
> and access the real command. This is the job of the `command` built-in
> command.**
>
> [However] the `command` command is not a special builtin command! Woe be to the shell programmer who defines a function named command! The POSIX
> standard provides the following two additional special qualities for
> the special built-in commands:
>
> 1. A syntax error in a special built-in utility may cause a shell executing that utility to abort, while a syntax error in a regular
>    built-in utility shall not cause a shell executing that utility to
>    abort. If a special built-in utility encountering a syntax error does
>    not abort the shell, its exit value shall be nonzero.
> 2. Variable assignments specified with special built-in utilities remain in effect after the built-in completes; this shall not be the
>    case with a regular built-in or other utility. [That is] you can
>    specify variable assignment at the front of a command and the variable
>    will have that value in the environment of the executed command only,
>    without affecting the variable in the current shell or subsequent
>    commands. (e.g. `PATH=/bin:/usr/bin: awk '...'`) However, when such an
>    assignment is used with a special built-in command, the assignment
>    stays in effect from then on, even after the special built-in
>    completes.

Arnold Robbins and Nelson H. F. Beebe. Classic Shell Scripting: Hidden Commands that Unlock the Power of Unix (p. 262-5). O'Reilly Media. Kindle Edition.

Note that the `command` command causes the shell to treat the specified command and arguments as a simple command, suppressing shell function lookup. From the [IBM Docs](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=c-command-command)

> Normally, when a / (slash) does not precede a command (indicating a
> specific path), the shell locates a command by searching the following
> categories:
>
> special shell built-ins shell functions regular shell built-ins PATH
> environment variable For example, if there is a function with the same
> name as a regular built-in, the system uses the function. The command
> command allows you to call a command that has the same name as a
> function and get the simple command.
>
> The command -v and command -V commands write to standard output what
> path name will be used by the shell and how the shell interprets the
> command type (built-in, function, alias, and so forth). Since the -v
> and -V flags produce output in relation to the current shell
> environment, the command command is provided as a Korn shell or POSIX
> shell regular built-in command. The /usr/bin/command command might not
> produce correct results, because it is called in a subshell or
> separate command execution environment,. In the following example the
> shell is unable to identify aliases, subroutines, or special shell
> commands:
>
> (PATH=foo command -v) nohup command -v

Thus, in my previous example, I used the bash `builtin` instead of `command` because had I put it in a subshell, it would not have worked properly.

I second @mosvy: it appears the standard and normative text don't match (quite absurd indeed).